# Self Join bringing too many records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join, self-join

I have this query to express a set of business rules. 
To get the information I need, I tried joining the table on itself but that brings back many more records than are actually in the table. Below is the query I've tried. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.rep_id, a.rep_name, count(*) AS 'Single Practitioner'
FROM [SE_Violation_Detection] a inner join [SE_Violation_Detection] b 
ON a.rep_id = b.rep_id and a.hcp_cid = b.hcp_cid
group by a.rep_id, a.rep_name
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Does this violations table have a column to indicate the violation type? Does each row reflect the rep, practitioner, product, and violation type?

Comment: Each row reflects the rep, practitioner, and product. It does not reflect the violation type. I have to figure that out based on the data and the business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a simpler way to get the information I need for one of the queries. The one above is still wrong.

```
--Rep violation for different HCP more than 5 times 
select distinct rep_id,rep_name,count(distinct hcp_cid) 
AS 'Multiple Practitioners' 
from dbo.SE_Violation_Detection
group by rep_id,rep_name 
having count(distinct hcp_cid)>4 
order by count(distinct hcp_cid)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with the having clause:

```
select a, b, count(*) c
from etc
group by a, b
having count(*) >= some number
```